# How do I take a crash dump on Linux?

Tags: dump, crash-dumps

I want to take a crash dump after the specified process crashed.

I typically use `PTRACE_ATTACH` and `waitpid()` to wait for the signal received from the targeted process, It works when the process is sent the signal by the system. BUT when the process crashed, `waitpid()` returns -1 as signal and the process exited at the same time, I almost have no time to trigger `gcore` command. (no such process).

How can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with "go"? There doesn't seem to be anything Go specific to your question, and it doesn't seem to be about programming either. You can ask general questions about software on superuser.com. There seems to be a lot that you can find with Google as well. Coredumps are generated by default when an app crashes, unless that default has been overridden (as it often is) in your system settings, but you can often override that for a specific process.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt sorry for the tag confusion.  I just want to use golang to implement it.

Comment: Coredumps are generated by default when a process exits unexpectedly. It's not possible do trigger that using waitpid as the process is already gone by that time, as you mentioned. You need to figure out how it was disabled on your particular distro/machine and enable it, at least for the process. Details differ depending on how it was disabled.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yep, I know. But not all signals can trigger the system to take a dump. That's why I have to write the code to implement it.

Comment: You should include that information in the question, including the signals that you need that don't generate a core dump for you.